# Ionic Native InAppPurchase2 - Can't get Store to load with .ready()

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

I've been having some trouble with the InAppPurchase2 plugin for Ionic Native in which all I'm trying to do is get the store to load when my component loads, though I'm not having any luck.

In my component, I'm doing the following:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.inAppPurchase2.ready().then(() => this.product = 'InAppPurchase plugin called');
    });
  }
```

According to the docs on the Ionic Native page for the plugin, using the `.ready()` function returns a promise, though when I run this on my device, this code never runs and I don't get an error.

I found a post somewhere else that says you can do something like `InAppPurchase2.getPlugin().ready(() => this.product = 'InAppPurchase plugin called'));` and call the function directly from the module, though I'm not having any luck with that either and anything else I try gives me errors in my typescript code.

Is there something I'm missing with what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: how do you know it's not running? Have you tried putting a log inside the callback function to see if it is being called?

Comment: Yes sorry, I have {{product}} in my html template to see if it shows that message and it doesn't :/

Comment: I have the same problem too with ionic 4.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is populate a property asynchronously.

do this:
make a function that calls the ready() function of the plugin and returns a string of your choice on promise resolve.

```
    makeAPromiseCall(): Promise<any> {
        return this.InAppPurchase2
            .ready()
            .then(() => 'InAppPurchasePlugin');
    }
```

assign this promise to your property as in

```
this.product: Promise<any> = this.makeAPromiseCall();
```

and in your html use the angular async pipe.

```
{{product | async}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had some trouble with this before. Sometimes the "ready" event does not fire as you would expect. Here is some code that I used to make this work

```
  constructor(public store: InAppPurchase2) {} ...

  this.store.ready().then((status) => {
    this.logger.logEvent('store_ready', {});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.store.get(productId)));
    console.log('Store is Ready: ' + JSON.stringify(status));
    console.log('Products: ' + JSON.stringify(this.store.products));
  });
  // This is what is missing...
  this.store.refresh();
```

Hopefully this helps. You have to also register the products individually. I did a brief explanation of this in a [blog post](https://medium.com/@andrew.thielcole/in-app-purchases-with-ionic-3-af13b21f49f2). You need to call refresh to get the store in a ready state.

Comment: I notice that adding  this.store.refresh(); indeed trigger the event but the documentation clearly say that we need to avoid the refresh method as much as we can because it is computationally expensive and requires the user to sign-in with Apple ID. Ref: https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/blob/master/doc/api.md